# Something phishy going on with email

Tags: email, phishing, email-spoofing

I own my own domain.  For a month or so I've been getting emails from addresses I don't know  with "see attached image" or "find the attached invoice", with a zip/rar file attached.  Of course, I deleted these.

Starting yesterday things have changed.  I am receiving emails more frequently (several per day), and instead of being addressed to me, they are return emails (from random SMTP servers on the net), telling me that my message could not be delivered.  The initial source of the message is spoofed to be some random name, at my domain.  The message content still says things like "see the attached invoice" with what was (before the rejection) an attachment.

What might be going on here?

Comment: Suggests that a spammer has used your address as the return address on a mail campaign. Check that you have SPF records set up for your domain, to make sure you have repudiation and ignore the responses - they'll probably be from ISPs that don't check SPF headers.

Comment: @Matthew - my mail server is set up to not relay for anyone except myself.  How does that relate to the SPF issue?  Thanks!

Comment: They probably aren't relaying. They're just faking the sender address. If a receiving server gets a message claiming to be from an SPF enabled host, it should just reject it, but not all ISPs do this. Therefore, you minimise the impact to yourself by ensuring that any attempts to use your email address in this way get rejected by reputable ISPs.